# Why does rename cause a file add rather than file changed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I accidentally added and committed a file with the wrong name.  No problem.  Tortoise has a rename command.  The command deleted the original and added the new file.

Is this just a short cut for copy, delete, and add?  Does this command do anything else behind the scenes?

Comment: For the record, modern VCSes, particularly DVCSes like Bazaar, and I think, now, Mercurial (not sure about Git) support fully rename and move as atomic operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apart from just being a short-cut, it also links the history to the new file so you can still see previous revisions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no such thing as rename in svn - its just the operations you described above.

Interestingly, there isn't even any such thing as move - see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html

Edit:  you shouldn't have any problems since you committed first, but this seems to be on topic anyway:  [SVN rename - pitfalls to avoid](http://juicebar.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/svn-rename-pitfalls-to-avoid/)